# Why Winston 3.0.0 is not working with Sails 0.12?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, winston

I have these settings in the file `config/log.js`

```
let {transports: transp, createLogger} = require('winston');    
let commonSettings = {
    colorize: false,
    maxsize: 10000000,
    maxfiles: 10,
    timestamp: true
};

let settings = [{ filename: 'logs/warn.log', level: 'warn' }];    
let logger = createLogger({
    transports: settings.map(s => new transp.File({...s, ...commonSettings}))
});

module.exports.log = {
    custom: logger,
    inspect: false
};
```

When I'm trying to start the Sails server using this command `sails lift`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.write is not a function
  at Function.DerivedLogger.(anonymous function) (node_modules/winston/lib/winston/create-logger.js:45:14)
  at Function._writeLogToConsole [as error] (node_modules/captains-log/lib/write.js:78:16)
  at Sails.runBootstrap (node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:56:17)
  at Sails.bound [as runBootstrap] (node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
  at Sails.initialize (node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:48:9)
  at bound (node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:607:21
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
  at iterate (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:612:34
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:201:13
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:451:17
  at /Users/egomezr/Documents/stack/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:441:17
  at _each (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
  at Immediate.taskComplete (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:440:13)
  at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:101:23)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are following the docs for ver. 3.0.0? For example, creating the transport requires only path and level as arguments, not what you supply.

Comment: @logout I'm sure these settings are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks Sails makes a sort of binding into the Winston logger, therefore, the logger loses some functionalities.

**Open issue:** [issues/4337](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4337)

**I found a workaround to get it work:**

```
let commonSettings = {
    colorize: false,
    maxsize: 10000000,
    maxfiles: 10,
    json: false
};

let settings = [
    {filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/warn.log`, level: 'warn'},
    {filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/error.log`, level: 'error'},
    {filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/debug.log`, level: 'debug'},
    {filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/info.log`, level: 'info'}
];

let {transports, createLogger, format} = require('winston');
let loggerSettings = {
    transports: [...settings.map(s => new transports.File({...s, ...commonSettings})), new transports.Console({
        format: format.simple()
    })],
    exitOnError: false
};

// This is the workaround
let winstonLogger = createLogger(loggerSettings);
let logger = {
    'info': function () {
        winstonLogger.info(...arguments);
    },
    'debug': function () {
        winstonLogger.debug(...arguments);
    },
    'error': function () {
        winstonLogger.error(...arguments);
    },
    'warn': function () {
        winstonLogger.warn(...arguments);
    },
    'log': function () {
        winstonLogger.log(...arguments);
    }
};
// End of workaround

module.exports.log = {
    custom: logger,
    inspect: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, it looks like his was reported in Sails issues but was inadvertently closed in https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4209.

Comment: Yes, I think it would nice to re-open that issue.  **Open issue:** [issues/4337](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4337)